# maximal independent set in a graph

Tags: general-topology, combinatorics, graph-theory

Let $G$ be a graph and $A$ is a subset of vertex set of $G$. $A$ is said to be independent if for any $x, y \in A$, $(x,y) \notin E(G)$, i.e $x$ and $y$ not connected by an edge. Further A is said to be maximal independent if A is not contained in  any  other independent set. Does anyone knows about any software with the help of that we can compute all the maximal independent set of a graph $G$ or any one provide me a any programing code for that. I know little bit about Matlab and  C++.

Comment: Unless you are dealing with bipartite graphs, the maximum independent set problem is NP-Hard. Of course, by trying to find a maximal independent set, you'll in turn be trying to find a maximum independent set.

Answer (score 1):

I think [Cliquer](http://users.tkk.fi/pat/cliquer.html) can do the work.

> **Summary**
>
> Cliquer is a set of C routines for finding cliques in an arbitrary weighted graph. It uses an exact branch-and-bound algorithm developed by Patric Östergård. It is designed with the aim of being efficient while still being flexible and easy to use.
>
> Cliquer was developed on Linux, and it should compile without modification on most modern UNIX systems. Other operating systems may require minor changes to the source code.

Note that, cliques are the dual of independent sets.